# Tamper with http requests programmatically

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-post

I need to sign in to a site, I can do this via an url such as url.com/ssorequest?parameters=123. If this is typed in the address im signed in in and gets redirected to the portal.

Now Im supposed to do this through a http post request programmatically but I cant get it to work, I get redirected to a sign in form instead of the portal, ie I dont get signed in.

I used Fiddler to find out what the difference between the two methods was. I found that a couple of behind-the-scenes get-requests were different. The browsers get-requests sends cookie data to the server and fiddlers post-request does not.

When I use fiddler to repeat the browsers first call it doesnt send the cookie data either. So it only works when I do it via the browser window. Unless I use breakpoints in fiddler and tamper with the requests to include the cookie data.

Q: Why does it behave differently from the browser with both http post and when the request is done from Fiddler?

Q: Is there any way to tamper with the requests going out programmatically in my C# app without writing my own Fiddler application?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have encountered an [anti-forgery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.antiforgerytoken%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) cookie. It works in a way to ensure that you are signing in using the page that was first requested and loaded in the browser and the cookie is valid for one request only and hence the fiddler will not be able to log in if you run the same request again.

Using C#, you first have to request the sign-in page and get the cookies provided with this page in a cookie container. Next time, when you post the page along with data, you have to make sure that the cookie is attached with the request.

Edit:

Step1: Browse any page on the site. This will initiate the session. It will also give you the session cookie.

Step2: Request the sign in page. send the cookie obtained in step one along with sign in page so that it can recognize the session. This step is critical. At this stage, there can be either of two things depending on the security system site is using. Either it will send a security cookie along with session cookie or it will add a hidden variable in the form along with a value which serves as security token. Make sure that you get this token/cookie.

Step2: Post the login information on the sign in page (or whatever page the form action leads to) along with the cookie/token obtained in step 1. If it is a token, include it in your post data along with login information or if a cookie, add it to request.

Comment: But if I make a brand new get-request in fiddler (just as the one done from the browser) it should be treated exactly like the browser one? (There is no trace from the first request in the second get-request in fiddler). Its just a new request but it doesnt behave the same for some reason...

Comment: There is only one difference. When you create request through browser, it maintains session while fiddler does not. It is not aware of previous requests. In order to successfully log in using fiddler or from your C# code, it is important that you also send cookies from the previous request though which you fetched the login page.

Comment: So I go to the sign in site (where I get a session id cookie). Request the next url and send in the cookie. And request the third url and send in the response I got from the second request? Problem is with the second url, it wants the session ID in the url aswell as a cookie containing the same id. When I give it this info in fiddler I get a response saying its an Illegal SSL param...